# How to clone existing Filevault encrypted HD to SSD with a linux live cd/usb

Tags: macbook-pro, hard-drive, ssd, filevault, migration

I have a 13-inch, Mid 2012 MacBook pro which comes with a 500 GB sata hard drive. I'm running 10.9.5 Mavericks. Of the 500 GB I have about 77 GB used whereas the rest of it is free space, this drive is encrypted with Filevault.

I have recently bought myself a 256 GB SSD from Amazon that I got for a good Cyber Monday deal, I want to clone this drive onto my new drive. I don't have a connector for the SSD drive to plug it in via a USB port and I'm wondering if I can do without one.

I have an external 2 TB hard drive, I'm thinking if I can boot my mac off a linux USB, I should be able to clone the existing hard drive with something like `dd` as a raw file on my external hard drive, then trim the raw image to remove the empty blocks, then start the mac with the `SSD` plugged in, flash the SSD with the raw image and then resize the partition so that all of the 256 GB of the SSD are available.

To me this sounds like a solid plan and I should be able to google around and figure out the commands to do all of this, I however have one concern around Filevault - will I be able to trim the partition after creating a clone on the external hard drive. I don't know if this part is possible.

Can someone confirm if this is possible, if not please suggest how you would do something like this.

Answer (score 1):

For Mac with FileVault 2, it is better to get a same sized SSD and use the following software to clone from your existing hard disc:

- Shirt Pocket's SuperDuper!,
- or Bombich Software's Carbon Copy Cloner

You wouldn't want to mess up any file or your existing system configuration with dd command especially when you have unequal-sized hard disc. And yes, 500 GB SSD is not cheap and you might need to re-sell your existing SSD, or otherwise you're risking an incomplete copy of your system which might haunt you later on.

reference: http://www.imore.com/how-easily-clone-your-mac-using-superduper-or-carbon-copy-cloner

If you are insisting on migrating from your existing hard disc to current 256 GB SSD, you may need another hard disc to be created as Time Machine backup, and then restore it back to your current SSD.

reference: https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/48798/cloning-a-half-full-500-gb-drive-to-a-256-gb-ssd-drive

Answer (score 1):

Late to the party, but my advice for future reference would be to save yourself a lot of time and hassle trying to work around FileVault by **disabling it** before you clone.

It may take several hours to decrypt the drive, but (IMO) this is time well-spent if it saves you the sanity of having to clone an encrypted drive.

Regarding the actual process of cloning the drive, there's a lot of guides already out there, however my process would be the following:

1. Disable FileVault
2. Trim the partition down to **at most** 200GB - this will make sure that all of your data fits into your new SSD.
3. Clone your drives & switch them over
4. Boot to your new SSD and expand the partition
5. Re-enable FileVault

It may sound like a round-about way of doing it, but you don't want to take unnecessary risks - even if you have Time Machine backups!

Comment: I don't have the option of disabling FileVault as this is my company issued mac and this is explicitly forbidden.

Comment: In that case, you should ask your company to upgrade the drive for you. Replacing hardware in company-issued equipment is just asking for trouble, and may very well be against your company's IT policy.